# using a return value inside a new object in javascript

Tags: javascript

This is probably too simple, but the object syntax is getting to me.

I have a simple function, that returns a string perfectly fit for using as arguments on an object, so:

```
function createString() {

// yadda yadda yadda

    return myPerfectstring;
}
```

and then there's this object, which should take `myPerfectstring` as a value like this:

```
new myPlayer({
        this: "#that",
        css: "#theOther"
    },
        //  insert myPerfectstring here
        // if I log it to the console and copy-paste here, everything works wonders
    , {
        other: "nana",
        things: "yeah",
        around: "yeahyeah"
    });
```

i know i can't just throw the function there, neither store it in a variable and insert, so, how do i go about entering that string as if it were really part of the object?

Comment: You have to be more concrete, provide a better example. `newPlayer` is a function and seems you want to pass three arguments to it. I don't understand the "object" part. Do you want `new myPlayer({...}, createString(), {...})`? What **is** `myPerfectstring`?

Comment: Do as Joseph Silber and thescientist says, or take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MQND7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't do this?  I'm having trouble determing how you are trying use the return value within the constructor.  as it's own property?

```
new myPlayer({
  this: "#that",
  css: "#theOther",
  string: createString(),
  other: "nana",
  things: "yeah",
  around: "yeahyeah"
});
```

Comment: this did it. Actually it was what i was trying to do from the beginning, but i didn't know the object would only take an array, not a string, and that's why it wasn't working and i thought using the function also wasn't.

Answer (score 2):

Just put it inline:

```
new myPlayer({
        this: "#that",
        css: "#theOther",
        theString: createString(),
        other: "nana",
        things: "yeah",
        around: "yeahyeah"
    });
```